# iOS Safari refresh button. Can I use it?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have some text field and I need refresh button like in Safari navigation bar.

**How can I use it instead of making my own?**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by... use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The refresh graphic itself can be extracted using [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor).  (Or, get a refresh icon from one of the many free iphone icon sets, like [Glyphish](http://glyphish.com/))

To place it in a UITextField like in Safari, set the UITextField rightView property to a UIImageView or UIButton with the image set to the refresh image.

```
UITextField* myTextField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,44)] autorelease];

myTextField.rightView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"UIButtonBarRefresh.png"]] autorelease];
```

You'll want to use a UIButton instead of a UIImageView if you want to get the TouchUpInside notification for the refresh button.

Comment: Can you give me some code snippet how to set rightView property?

Answer (score 3):

It's a custom safari widget.  You have to make your own.

Comment: The meaning is that the art isn't a native asset you can just call up.  You make it or get it from an icon set.